# Save widgets in Bundle outState

Tags: java, android

I am making a basic game in Android studio, and if the player rotates the screen, I want all the data to be saved. Hence, I use the *protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate)* and restore them with *protected void onRestoreInstanceStave(Bundle savedInstanceState)* and I have a few Buttons which have been manipulated programmatically. So how am I supposed to put the Button inside outState?

```
import ...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn1, btn2;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
        btn2 = findViewById (R.id.btn_no);
    }
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //How to put buttons in outState?
    }
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //How to get buttons in savedInstanceState?
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a whole widget in a bundle - even in your `onCreate()` method, btn1 and btn2 are only references to the ids of the buttons in the XML. You could probably save these ids (they'll be ints, so are saveable) in the savedInstanceState, but it would be fairly useless.

When an activity gets destroyed and recreated, the whole screen is redrawn. If you have made any changes to the button (text, colour, number count, etc.) the approach to recreate these changes would be to store any **values** in the bundle, then update the button with them in `onCreate()`